# Ruby If Statement Refactoring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, if-statement

I have a very simple Ruby question. Is there a way to refactor this:

```
<%= some_array.length if some_array.length > 1 %>
```

into something like

```
<%= some_array.length if self > 1 %>
```

where 'self' (for example) is references the initially calculated value - i.e. some_array.length?

Comment: This belongs on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Matheus, I'd say SO is ok, it's a very specific use case, not review of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to keep the main templates simple and pull logic into helpers. The erb can contain:

```
<%= display_length(some_array) %>
```

where the helper contains:

```
def display_length(array)
  array.length if array.length > 1
end
```

Of course, adjust the names to best represent your business logic.

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't do this. The statement doesn't evaluate left-to-right in the way you're assuming it does. The `if` statement is evaluated first, so there is no "self" to test. The "initially calculated value" as you put it, is calculated *first* by the `if` statement.

Comment: I had a feeling this was the case. @Mark Thomas: I ended up using your appraoch. Thanks to both!

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to compute it 2 time you can do it like this

```
<% len = some_array.length %>
<%= len if len > 1 %>
```

else you can create helper method. 
Initial question is bit misleading because left side of if will not be computed before right side so even if you could pass "your self" as computed value imagine (your pseudo code):

```
people.destroy_all if self > 100
```

This will compute destruction always to produce "your self" :D

Answer (score 0):

A. You can do something like this

```
<%= l = some_array.length if l > 1 %>
```

B. You can use [Presenter pattern](http://railscasts.com/episodes/287-presenters-from-scratch)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
length if (length = some_array.length) > 1
```

A bit esoteric, but shorter...

Comment: I'm afraid that `length` will get the result of the `some_array.length > 1` then (true or false). You need to parenthesize it.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is something more-or-less like this:

```
t = some_array.length; t if t > 1
```

Also, note that interpolated ERB expressions that are conditional (without an `else`) will return the value in the one case and `nil` in the other case.  The ERB implementation will evalute `result.to_s` and `#to_s` on `nil` produces "". So, it's a workable design pattern but perhaps not easily understood by all the code readers that will come later.

Answer (score -2):

```
class Object
  def block_scope
    yield self
    [] # Required for HAML and probably ERB as well
  end
end
```

ERB:

```
<% array.length.block_scope do |l| %>
  <%= l if l > 1 %>
<% end %>
```

HAML:

```
- array.length.block_scope do |l|
  = l if l > 1
```

A little better visually than simple assignment

**UPDATE**

Agree that adding `block_scope` to `Object` namespace is definitely overkill for views, much better solution would be creating a helper:

```
def block_scope(*args)
  yield *args
  [] #?
end

- block_scope(array.length) do |l|
  = l if l > 1
```

Comment: This is an utterly grotesque solution. It's more verbose than a simple `if` statement and has the extremely gross side-effect of polluting every single object with a generically named method that is useless 99.999% of the time. It doesn't accomplish either goal of less typing or fewer evaluations of `array.length`. As far as being "visually better", this is pretty subjective, but I think you're dead wrong on that point too; it's ugly as sin. This kind of things is what helpers are for. Sorry if this sounds harsh, but it's important to make sure new Rubyists don't think this is a good solution.

Comment: @meagar I does accomplish fewer evaluations (doesn't make much sense for Array#length though), besides generally we are not talking about one-line block, it can be useful for bigger blocks, especially with argument destructuring. It is not clear from this example though.